# Python: try-except, doesn't call try when it should

Tags: python, zip, try-except

I really don't know why my "try-except" doesn't run "try" even when it should.
It just prints the message from "except" with the correct password as "result".
I already tried a few things but nothing seems to work.

(I don't want to do something illegal with this programm. Im just interested in the itertools and zipfile module.)

Code:

```
import itertools, sys, zipfile

chars = input("Chars:" + " ")
max_length = input("Max length:" + " ")
zip_name = input("Zip name:" + " ")

max_length = int(max_length)

if chars in ("letters", "Letters"):
    chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
if chars in ("numbers", "Numbers"):
    chars = "0123456789"

print()

input("Press enter to start...")

print()

length = (max_length + 1) - max_length

zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name)

while length <= max_length:
    results = itertools.product(chars, repeat = length)
    for result in results:
        result = "".join(result)
        try:
            zip_file.extractall(pwd = result)
            print()
            print("Password found:", result)
            print("Sucessfully extracted all files from", zip_name + ".")
            print()
            input("Press enter to exit...")
            sys.exit()
        except:
            print("Password not yet found:", result)
    length = length + 1

print()
print("Couldn't find the password.")
```

Comment: A clear example of why you shouldn't use a bare except. The first line of the try block is probably causing an exception, but you're swallowing it so you'll never know what it is. Don't do that.

Comment: Are you sure you want `input` and not `raw_input`? `input` evaluates a Python expression, but I believe you're trying to get a string from the user.

Comment: Are you trying to crack a zipped file's password?

Comment: Read http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--/ - that is a profoundly unhelpful way of managing errors, from the point of view of both the user and the developer.

Comment: @dpwilson: as can be seen by the use of print() as a function, this is Python 3 code, where raw_input() was renamed to input(), and the old input() no longer exists as a built-in.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments/answers. I am pretty new to programming. Thanks for the tips! I also found the mistake... I didn't convert "result"-string to byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it looks like you have an exception on this line:

```
zip_file.extractall(pwd = result)
```

Then it goes to the except block.

*How to solve:* remove try/except and see what will appear in the output.

Comment: `traceback.print_exc()` can be added to the exception.